# IOS: performSelector:withObject: acts weird

Tags: ios, objective-c

my app turns out to be unable to load some content. I was surprised, and I found out that the bug was that

```
[contentItem performSelector:@selector(setIsContainer:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true]];
```

was passing **"False"** to the method instead of **"True"**.

Is there any explanation to this? Or I should, as a good practice, avoid using `performSelector`?

(I asked coworkers for their phones, and I took same `iPhone5s` with same `iOS` versions, in all 3 of them everything worked fine, except the boss' phone)

Comment: Exchange boss's phone with the "good" one. Solved! :)

Comment: It seems your error should not be in performSelector, Please check with NSLog to get exact error.

Comment: Show the implementation of `setIsContainer:`.

Comment: - (void)setIsContainer:(BOOL)isContainer
{
    //NSLog(@"isContainer is set");
    _isContainer = isContainer;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing an `NSNumber` object to a method which expects a `BOOL` primitive. It should fail on every version of iOS.

Change the implementation to:

```
- (void)setIsContainer:(NSNumber *)isContainer {
    _isContainer = [isContainer boolValue];
}
```

(if you require the original semantics then you'll have to provide an alternative version; one for `NSNumber` and one for `BOOL`).